# Reciprocal Cone

Tags: analytic-geometry, 3d, quadrics

Can anybody explain if the reciprocal cone of the cone touching the three axes will be the cone touching the three coordinate planes.
If yes, why?

$3$-D diagram would really help if possible. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

It turned out that the reciprocal cone is just what you get taking the inverse of the symmetric matrix that defined the first cone. I gave a big answer at [condition for cones to be reciprocal](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1714136/condition-for-cones-to-be-reciprocal/1714646#1714646)

I'm not going to post any diagrams.

The "cone touching the three axes" is
$$ yz + zx + xy = 0. $$ The matrix can be the Hessian matrix of second partial derivatives of the quadratic form. The basic rule is that the Hessian matrix have determinant not equal to zero.