# Show that the cones $ayz+bxz+cxy=0$ and $(ax)^{1/2}+(by)^{1/2}+(cz)^{1/2}=0$ are reciprocal.

Tags: geometry, algebraic-geometry, euclidean-geometry, 3d

Show that the cones $$ayz+bxz+cxy=0 \quad \text{and} \quad (ax)^\frac{1}{2}+(by)^\frac{1}{2}+(cz)^\frac{1}{2}=0$$
 are reciprocal, the formar contains the co-ordinate axes while the latter touch the coordinte planes.

Comment: Two questions 1) What is your definition of "reciprocal" ? 2) There is a problem with the second equation: $ (ax)^\frac{1}{2}+(by)^\frac{1}{2}+(cz)^\frac{1}{2}=0$ represents the "equation" of point $(0,0,0)$... with the usual meaning of power 1/2 (i.e. with $(...)^{1/2} \geq 0$). If you use a different meaning, you **must** explain it.

Comment: @JeanMarie  we found out what reciprocal cones meant, http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1714136/condition-for-cones-to-be-reciprocal/1714646#1714646     and http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1899004/reciprocal-cone

Comment: @Will Jagy Thanks for the definition.

Comment: @JeanMarie I don't think the OP is capable of answering your question. Reading the handwritten page he posted as an answer gives one possible interpretation that makes sense. I posted one of the three reasonable orderings as a new answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At some point I found the definition of reciprocal cone [in this book](https://books.google.com/books?id=iGgNBgAAQBAJ&pg=PP5&lpg=PP5&dq=vasishtha%20geometry%20vector%20calculus&source=bl&ots=A08rideSxm&sig=u97Lap3CN0L9STFAlwvD84-8Lxw&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjft97M8JzSAhVnxlQKHV1wCcIQ6AEIKDAC#v=onepage&q=vasishtha%20geometry%20vector%20calculus&f=false). I posted some relevant pages at [condition for cones to be reciprocal](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1714136/condition-for-cones-to-be-reciprocal/1714646#1714646) 
Alright, I was able to paste the same images here. Good to know how to do that, as I cannot seem to find those pages any more in the online book previews.

given cone $ayz + bzx + c xy = 0,$ the actual reciprocal cone is
$$ a^2 x^2 + b^2 y^2 + c^2 z^2 - 2bcyz - 2cazx - 2abxy = 0. $$

About the coordinate planes, what happens when $z =0?$ Then 
$$ a^2 x^2- 2abxy  + b^2 y^2  = (ax-by)^2 = 0, $$ so that
$$ ax = by.  $$
This is a single line, therefore the cone is tangent to the plane $z=0.$ 
Another way to confirm tangency is to point out that a point on this line is, for some $t,$ given by $(bt, at, 0).$ Furthermore, for a quadratic form given by $v^t H v,$ the gradient is given ( as a column vector) by $2 H v.$
We then calculate
$$
\left(
\begin{array}{rrr}
a^2 & -ab & -ca \\
-ab & b^2 & -bc \\
-ca & -bc & c^2
\end{array}
\right) 
\left(
\begin{array}{r}
bt \\
at \\
0
\end{array}
\right) =
\left(
\begin{array}{r}
0 \\
0 \\
-2abct
\end{array}
\right)
$$

$$
\left(
\begin{array}{rrr}
0& c & b \\
c & 0 & a \\
b & a & 0
\end{array}
\right)
\left(
\begin{array}{rrr}
a^2 & -ab & -ca \\
-ab & b^2 & -bc \\
-ca & -bc & c^2
\end{array}
\right) =
\left(
\begin{array}{rrr}
-2abc & 0 & 0 \\
0 & -2abc & 0 \\
0 & 0 & -2abc
\end{array}
\right)
$$

[image]

[image]

[image]

[This seems to be a pretty good practice/solutions manual](http://www.laxmipublications.com/servlet/lpgetbiblio?bno=001055) for this material

Comment: I am not understand.

Comment: Please upvote to my question.

Comment: @SarojGhosh I can't upvote you, because we don't know your question. Your question  has some grammatical and mathematical error. So I recommend another site (your own country's).

Comment: @Takahiro Waki ,my question is correct,you could not understand this .

Answer (score 0):

[image].I able to 1st part but i can not understand 2nd part.

Comment: I cannot understand the part about $\sqrt a x$ either. Were did you find this??? I don't see any way that describes a cone.

Comment: @Will jagy, sorry  somthing wrong in the last line , correct is (ax)^1/2+(by)1/2+(cz)^1/2=0

Comment: Because this is not cone, paraboloid.　They are similar shape, though.

Comment: With real constants $a,b,c, $ the equation $$ \sqrt {ax} +  \sqrt {by}  +  \sqrt {cz} = 0  $$ refers to the single point (with real variables) $$ x = y = z = 0. $$

Answer (score 0):

Alright, it turns out this was just **carelessness about square roots. IF**
$$  \color{blue}{ax \geq 0, \; b y \geq 0, \; cz \geq 0  }$$
**AND**
$$ \color{blue}{ \sqrt {cz} = \sqrt {ax} + \sqrt {by}},  $$
square once to get
$$ cz = ax + by + 2 \sqrt {abxy},  $$ so
$$ - ax - by + cz  = 2 \sqrt {abxy}.  $$  Squaring again does give
$$ a^2 x^2 + b^2 y^2 + c^2 z^2 - 2byz -2ca zx + 2abxy = 2abxy,  $$
$$ a^2 x^2 + b^2 y^2 + c^2 z^2 - 2byz -2ca zx - 2abxy = 0.  $$
**This is a subset of the cone in just one octant, and is not the entirety of cone points in that octant.**  We get three pieces when 
$$  \color{blue}{ax \geq 0, \; b y \geq 0, \; cz \geq 0  },$$
namely
$$ \color{blue}{ \sqrt {cz} = \sqrt {ax} + \sqrt {by}},  $$
$$ \color{blue}{ \sqrt {ax} = \sqrt {by} +  \sqrt {cz} },  $$
$$ \color{blue}{  \sqrt {by} = \sqrt {cz} + \sqrt {ax} }.  $$

There is no sense to taking all $+$ signs, as in
$$ \sqrt {ax} + \sqrt {by} + \sqrt {cz} = 0, $$ this can only be a single point!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!

The example $a=b=c=1,$ with $x,y,z \geq 0,$ and $\sqrt z = \sqrt x + \sqrt y$ gives the satisfactory
$$ z = x + y + 2 \sqrt {x y}. $$ This is part of a cone. We can write it in polar/cylindrical coordinates as $0 \leq \theta \leq \frac{\pi}{2},$ $$ z = r \; \left( \cos \theta + \sin \theta + 2 \sqrt { \cos \theta  \; \sin \theta} \right)  $$
Other points of the same cone in the first octant $x,y,z \geq 0,$ include $\sqrt x = \sqrt y + \sqrt z$  and $\sqrt y = \sqrt z + \sqrt x.$