# prove that the equation √fx ± √gy ± √hz=0 represents a cone which touches the co-ordinate planes.

Tags: geometry

I know the equation of a cone which touchez the co-ordinate axes are fyz+gzx+hxy=0. but I cannot solve the problem.

Comment: see answers to http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2151112/show-that-the-cones-ayzbxzcxy-0-and-ax1-2by1-2cz1-2-0-are

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Show that the cones $ayz+bxz+cxy=0$ and $(ax)^{1/2}+(by)^{1/2}+(cz)^{1/2}=0$ are reciprocal.](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2151112/show-that-the-cones-ayzbxzcxy-0-and-ax1-2by1-2cz1-2-0-are)

Comment: I corrected the title and voted to close (duplicate).

Comment: IF
$$  \color{blue}{ax \geq 0, \; b y \geq 0, \; cz \geq 0  }$$
then
$$ \color{blue}{ \sqrt {cz} = \sqrt {ax} + \sqrt {by}}  $$ defines a subset of a genuine cone, not the entire cone.

Comment: #aretino ,  I know it , but where I get the question I see that. So, I confuse about this. So I ask here